# Can a PHP script start before all POST data is received?

Tags: php, .net, apache

I'm running PHP under Apache and I'd like to send a slow trickle of POST data to the page that will write messages into a database as the POST data arrives. I'm sending the data from a .NET app using `WebRequest` and I've set `SendChunked` to true.

Unfortunately, it looks like the PHP script doesn't start executing until all the POST data has arrived. I looked in the apache log, and I see that the request starts right away, but `echo strftime(...)` statements in the PHP script show that it isn't running until after all the POST data was received.

Is there any way to tell PHP to start right away? I tried setting `always_populate_raw_post_data = Off` in the PHP.ini file, but that didn't make any difference. My request has a content type of `application/octet-stream`, and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is still filled with all the POST data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the [HTTP PUT](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) method, but not with POST.

When the client uses the PUT verb the data is streamed in to PHP. It can be accessed through the `php:://input` stream byte by byte as it is sent from the client.